# обращение по внутреннему id к json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется несколько JSON файлов, внутри которых есть ID. Выглядят они примерно так:

```
{
    "id":"fak4_kurs4_9",
    "faculty":"4",
    "course":"4",
    "group": "9",
    "schedule": [
        {
            "day": "понеділок",
            "pair": "3",
            "start": "12:05",
            "end": "13:25",
            "subject": "Л Моделювання та аналіз ПрЗаб  В",
            "room": "Б-505",
            "group": "вся",
            "teacher": ""
        },
```

И файл ajax.js который вызывает данный json:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#submit_form").click(
            function(){
                sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'formdata', 'action_ajax_form.php');
                return false; 
            }
        );
    });
    function sendAjaxForm(result_form, formdata, url) {
        $.ajax({
            url:    url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
            type:   "POST", //метод отправки
            dataType: "html", //формат данных
            data: $("#"+formdata).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
            success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
                result = $.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(result);
                if(result.grupa == 'fak4_kurs4_9')
                {
                    var scheduleTable = document.getElementById('schedule');
                    info = document.getElementById('info');
                    requestURL = 'data_rozklad_FIT_4_9.txt'; //файл находится в той же папке, что и html-файл, который к нему обращается
                }; 
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', requestURL);
                request.onload = function(e) 
                {
                    if (request.readyState === 4) 
                    {
                        if (request.status === 200) 
                        {
                            //console.log(request.response);
                            var dataTable = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                            getTableInfo(dataTable);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.error(request.statusText);
                        }
                    }           
                };
                request.onerror = function(e)
                {
                    console.error(request.statusText);
                };
                request.send();
                function getTableInfo(data) 
                {
                    info.innerHTML = 
                        '<p>Факультет: ${data.faculty}<p>
                        <p>Курс: ${data.course}</p> 
                        <p>Група: ${data.group}</p>
                        <p>Навчальний тиждень: <p>';
                    let headerTr = document.createElement('tr');
                    headerTr.innerHTML = 
                        '<th>День</th><th>Пара</th><th>Старт пари</th>
                        <th>Кінець пара</th><th>Предмет</th><th>Кабінет</th>
                        <th>Група</th><th>Викладач</th>';
                    scheduleTable.appendChild(headerTr);
                    //console.log(Array.isArray(data.schedule));
                    data.schedule.forEach(function(elem) 
                    {
                        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        tr.innerHTML = 
                            '<td>${elem.day}</td><td>${elem.pair}</td>
                            <td>${elem.start}</td><td>${elem.end}</td>
                            <td>${elem.subject}</td><td>${elem.room}</td>
                            <td>${elem.group}</td><td>${elem.teacher}</td>';
                        schedule.appendChild(tr);
                    });
                } 
                //$('#result_form').html('група: '+result.grupa);
            },
            error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
                $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
            }
        });
    }
});
`
```

Есть файл action_ajax_form.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["grupa"])) { 

    // Формируем массив для JSON ответа
    $result = array(
        'grupa' => $_POST["grupa"]
    ); 

    // Переводим массив в JSON
    echo json_encode($result); 
}

?>
```

И index.html, стоит ли приводить код, не знаю?

Я в форме выбираю факультет, курс, группу, данный запрос обрабатывается аяксом и загружается на страницу содержимое файла fak4_kurs4_9.txt. Посоветовали вызывать файл по внутреннему ID, а не по названию файла
Не могу разобраться, как вызывать файл по ID, а не по названию файла. Мне подсказали про метод map, но не могу понять как его применить к своему файлу.

Comment: у вас ошибка `id: "fak4_kurs4_9"` в кавычках должно быть

Comment: Кавычки не самая большая проблема, вопрос был в другом

Comment: Он и дальше существует, есть что-то по существу вопроса, который выше?

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но не то. Вы суть проблемы читали?

Comment: всё понял - прочитал - сорри

Answer (score 0):

Как вообще звучит изначально постановка здачачи? По выбранным факультету, курсу и группе найти расписание и вывести его, а расписания разложены по файлам в формате json? Что за метод map и куда его тут применять тоже не ясно. Про него стоит просить у советчика.